# cut even lines and merge to upper line

Tags: command-line, text-processing, text-editor

I have a file like with CRLF line terminators:

```
Green Day: Rock Band Xbox 360
3074
Green Hell Steam
27015-27030, 27036-27037
Green Hell Switch
6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Adios Steam

Adios Xbox One

Adore Playstation 4
3074, 3478-3479
```

It also have some empty line in even lines.
How can I cut even lines and append to its upper line?
like this: (comma after first line is necessary)

```
first line, second line

Green Day: Rock Band Xbox 360, 3074
Green Hell Steam, 27015-27030, 27036-27037
Green Hell Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Adios Steam,
Adios Xbox One,
Adore Playstation 4, 3074, 3478-3479
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line has a couple of methodes `paste` is pretty neat.

Comment: Wait, there are empty lines? That changes everything. Are they in the same file? Can you show us the full file? Will the empty lines change the line numbering? Can we still assume you want to only cut even lines and not odd ones?

Comment: yes there are some empty lines in the same file, but it doesn't change the order of lines. Only even lines can be empty.

Comment: Have you ever opened the file in Windows? Can it have Windows line endings?

Comment: Yes, result: 
filename: Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: Please edit that into your question, it is essential information and is why the solutions you have been given don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

first, pass your input file in `dos2unix` utility to remove windows line ending `\r`.

```
$ awk 'NR%2{printf "%s, ", $0;next}1' file
Green Day: Rock Band Xbox 360, 3074
Green Hell Steam, 27015-27030, 27036-27037
Green Hell Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Adios Steam, 
Adios Xbox One, 
Adore Playstation 4, 3074, 3478-3479
```

Comment: It didn't work. It only added a comma in front of even lines.

Comment: Please, stop changing input since you have answers. Edited my post. Anything wrong?

Comment: Now I have: firstline[nextline] comma [space] secondline.

Comment: I have exactly the expected output from your original question

Comment: filename: Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with CRLF line terminators
I think because it has been edited in Windows it doesn't work for me.
But I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Added mention of `dos2unix` tool